# Integers to English words in C

Tags: beginner, c, numbers-to-words

As a beginner in C programming, I decided to write a function `words` that, given an unsigned integer `n`, puts the English representation in words of `n` into the character array `dest`.

This code is quite difficult to follow due to its complexity. If I hadn't written this code, it would take me a good while to understand it fully. What can I do to improve readability and reduce the unnecessary complexity?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const char *digits[] = { "one ", "two ", "three ", "four ", "five ", "six ", "seven ", "eight ", "nine " };
const char *tens[] = { "ten ", "twenty ", "thirty ", "forty ", "fifty ", "sixty ", "seventy ", "eighty ", "ninety " };
const char *teens[] = { "eleven ", "twelve ", "thirteen ", "fourteen ", "fifteen ", "sixteen ", "seventeen ", "eighteen ", "nineteen " };
const char *hundreds[] = { "thousand ", "million ", "billion " };

char *strprep(const char *prefix, char *dest)
{
    char *temp = strdup(dest);
    sprintf(dest, "%s%s", prefix, temp);
    free(temp);
    return dest;
}

void words(unsigned int n, char *dest)
{
    unsigned int l, r, m, d = 0, t = 0;
    char d_cpy[16];

    while(n)
    {
        r = n % 10;
        n = (n - r) / 10;
        m = d % 3;

        if(d && !m)
        {
            if(r || n % 100)
            {
                strprep(hundreds[t], dest);
            }

            t++;
        }

        if(r)
        {
            switch(m)
            {
                case 0:
                    if(n % 10 != 1)
                    {
                        strprep(digits[r - 1], dest);
                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    if(l && r == 1)
                    {
                        strprep(teens[l - 1], dest);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        strprep(tens[r - 1], dest);
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    strcpy(d_cpy, digits[r - 1]);
                    strprep(strcat(d_cpy, "hundred "), dest);
            }
        }

        l = r;
        d++;
    }

    if(!strlen(dest))
    {
        strcpy(dest, "zero");
    }
}
```

To provide some context, `words()` is called in `main()` (defined in the same file):

```
#include <limits.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *last;
    unsigned long int n;

    if(argc != 2)
    {
        puts("incorrect number of arguments!");
        printf("usage: %s [integer]\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    n = strtoul(argv[1], &last, 10);

    if(*last || !(*argv[1]) || n > UINT_MAX)
    {
        puts("first argument must be a valid integer");
        return -1;
    }

    char buf[256];
    puts(words((unsigned int)n, buf));
}
```

Comment: Posting examples usages of `words()`, or at least a description of how to use it would be helpful and allow even better answers.

Comment: This is a small thing but putting the opening braces on the previous line rather than on its own line would *vastly** increase the readability of this particular piece of code (for one thing, the whole `words` function would now comfortably fit onto a single screen, rather than requiring scrolling).

Comment: @KonradRudolph that's really a style preference. I personally find it __vastly__ more legible when opening braces are on their own line rather than trailing the previous line.

Comment: @jcaron I don’t buy it, sorry. Try it for OP’s code: it’s so obviously more readable, there’s nothing I can add. Everybody always harps on about not exceeding horizontal space but vertical space *also* affects readability, and there are in fact multiple studies to back this up (*Code Complete* references some research).

Comment: An efficient way to do this if the function must be called often is to set up a persistent array containing the names of every number between $0$ and $999$. Here is relatively readable SQL code that does just that and defines a function like you need: https://users.drew.edu/skass/sql/nameMoney.sql.txt . I think you could adapt this to C, using a static local variable in the function to hold the names of $0$ to $999$ and with conditional code in the function that initializes the array if the array is uninitialized when the function is called.

Comment: @KonradRudolph : Could we take discussion of [indentation style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) to ["Should curly braces appear on their own line?"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2715/should-curly-braces-appear-on-their-own-line) ?

Comment: @DavidCary It’s great of you to mention that question because there, too, all the actual evidence mentioned points to the fact that braces on the same line objectively improve readability. Whereas proponents of braces-on-their-own-line have nothing to back up their preference, just opinions.

Comment: @KonradRudolph They do not improve legibility. That is obvious. Allman All The Time.

Comment: @Almo Right, I see we’re completely giving up on factual arguments. Perfect for a code review site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Design

Your function **fails to write a NUL terminator** at the end of the output.  That means that the caller must zero the entire buffer before calling the function (or else use a `static` buffer).

The output does have a superfluous space at the end, though.

As a rule, whenever you call a function to write to a string buffer, you **must also pass the buffer's size**.  Otherwise, the function has no way of knowing when to stop before the **buffer overflows**.  (That's why poorly designed functions such as [`gets(char *buf)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gets.html) and [`sprintf(char *s, const char *format, …)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sprintf.html) should be shunned, and you should use the safer alternatives `fgets(char *s, int n, FILE *stream)` and `snprintf(char *s, size_t n, const char *format, …)` instead.)

Therefore, I recommend that `words()` be designed similar to `snprintf()`: it should accept one more parameter for the buffer size, and it should return the length of the string that was written (or should have been written).

It's annoying that your string arrays are off **"off by one"**, such that you have to write `-1` in `digits[r - 1]`, `teens[l - 1]`, and `tens[r - 1]`.

The **`hundreds` array is altogether misnamed**, as it has nothing to do with hundreds.  I'd call it [`scales`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_and_short_scales).

### Algorithm and implementation

Your string manipulation is inefficient:

- **Prepending** any string (using `strprep()`) involves copying characters.  It would be worthwhile to rework the algorithm such that it only needs to write its output sequentially and never needs to prepend anything.
- If you *did* have to prepend a string, it would be smarter to avoid allocating a temporary string using `strdup()`, then freeing it.  Using `memmove()`, with **no temporarily allocated memory**, would be smarter.

By the way, the `strprep()` function, being a helper function, should be declared `static`.

The special case…

> ```
> if(!strlen(dest))
> {
>     strcpy(dest, "zero");
> }
> ```

… should be handled at the very beginning of `words()`, using `if (n == 0)`, **avoiding `strlen()`**, which would have to traverse the output character by character to determine the length.  (And remember, `strlen()` doesn't even work, since you don't ensure that the output is NUL-terminated.)

`n = (n - r) / 10` can be simply written as `n /= 10`.

Nobody likes to read code with uncommented **cryptic variable names** like this:

> ```
> unsigned int l, r, m, d = 0, t = 0;
> ```

After staring at your code for a *very* long time, I have figured out that…

- `d` is the exponent of 10 (and would probably be better named `exponent`).
- `t` is just `d / 3` (and should therefore be eliminated).
- `m` is just `d % 3` (and should therefore be eliminated).
- `r` is the rightmost digit currently being considered.
- `l` is the digit to the right of `r`.

### Minimal rewrite

Here is a slightly revised version of your code, with the following goals:

- `NUL` terminator
- `strprep()` without a temporary string allocation
- character arrays without the off-by-one annoyance
- simpler special case for `0`
- fewer variables, with more intuitive names

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const char *digits[] = { NULL, "one ", "two ", "three ", "four ", "five ", "six ", "seven ", "eight ", "nine " };
const char *tens[] = { NULL, "ten ", "twenty ", "thirty ", "forty ", "fifty ", "sixty ", "seventy ", "eighty ", "ninety " };
const char *teens[] = { "ten ", "eleven ", "twelve ", "thirteen ", "fourteen ", "fifteen ", "sixteen ", "seventeen ", "eighteen ", "nineteen " };
const char *scales[] = { "", "thousand ", "million ", "billion " };

static void strprep(const char *prefix, char *dest) {
    size_t prefix_len = strlen(prefix);
    memmove(dest + prefix_len, dest, strlen(dest) + 1);
    memcpy(dest, prefix, prefix_len);
}

void words(unsigned int n, char *dest) {
    if (n == 0) {
        strcpy(dest, "zero");
        return;
    }

    *dest = '\0';

    int prev_digit;
    for (int exponent = 0; n; exponent++) {
        int digit = n % 10,
            remaining_digits = n / 10;

        if ((exponent % 3 == 0) && (n % 1000)) {
            strprep(scales[exponent / 3], dest);
        }

        if (digit) {
            switch (exponent % 3) {
              case 0:
                if (remaining_digits % 10 != 1) {
                    strprep(digits[digit], dest);
                }
                break;
              case 1:
                if (digit == 1) {
                    strprep(teens[prev_digit], dest);
                } else {
                    strprep(tens[digit], dest);
                }
                break;
              case 2:
                strprep("hundred ", dest);
                strprep(digits[digit], dest);
                break;
            }
        }

        prev_digit = digit;
        n = remaining_digits;
    }
}
```

### Suggested solution

I recommend using a completely different algorithm, because:

- For efficiency, the algorithm needs to always append, never prepend.
- You need to keep track of the number of bytes written, so as to avoid buffer overflow.
- Your algorithm is hard to understand.  When considering the ones digit, it needs to look ahead to see whether the tens digit is `1`, in which case it should temporarily output nothing.  When considering the tens digit, if it's `1`, then it needs to consult the previously saved ones digit (which is the only place where `l` is used).

  I recommend considering groups of three digits at a time, so that you have a variable which represents the hundreds, the tens, and the ones digit.

This ends up being a lot of `snprintf()` calls, keeping track of the number of characters written.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static const char *digits[] = {
    "", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five",
    "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"
};
static const char *teens[] = {
    "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen",
    "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen"
};
static const char *tens[] = {
    "", "ten", "twenty", "thirty", "forty",
    "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"
};
static const char *scales[] = { "", "thousand", "million", "billion" };

/**
 * Given 0 <= n < 1000, writes n as English words to buf, followed by a NUL
 * terminator.  If n == 0, then just a NUL terminator is written.
 *
 * Returns the length of the output written, excluding the NUL terminator
 * (or the length of the string that should have been written, if the return
 * value is greater than or equal to the buffer size).
 */
static int words1k(int n, char *buf, size_t size) {
    assert(0 <= n && n < 1000);
    int h = n / 100,
        t = (n % 100) / 10,
        o = (n % 10);
    switch (t) {
      case 0:
        return snprintf(buf, size, "%s%s%s%s",
            digits[h], (h ? " hundred" : ""),
            (h && o ? " " : ""), digits[o]);
      case 1:
        return snprintf(buf, size, "%s%s%s",
            digits[h], (h ? " hundred " : ""), teens[o]);
      default:
        return snprintf(buf, size, "%s%s%s%s%s",
            digits[h], (h ? " hundred " : ""),
            tens[t], (t && o ? "-" : ""), digits[o]);
    }
}

/**
 * Writes n as English words to buf, followed by a NUL terminator.
 * (A buffer size of 120 is recommended.)
 *
 * Returns the length of the output written, excluding the NUL terminator
 * (or the length of the string that should have been written, if the return
 * value is greater than or equal to the buffer size).
 */
int words(unsigned int n, char *buf, size_t size) {
    size_t len = 0;
    if (n == 0) {
        return snprintf(buf, size, "zero");
    } /* else if (n < 0) {
        int nlen = snprintf(buf, size, "negative ");
        len = words(-n, buf + nlen, (size > nlen ? size - nlen : 0));
        return nlen + len;
    } */
    for (int s = 3, scale = 1000000000; s >= 0; s--, scale /= 1000) {
        // If there was any previous output, leave room for a space after it
        int start_pos = len ? len + 1 : 0;
        int klen = words1k(n / scale, buf + start_pos, (size > start_pos ? size - start_pos : 0));
        // If there was previous output and recent output, then write the space
        if (len && klen) {
            if (len < size) buf[len] = ' ';
            len++;
        }
        len += klen;
        if (klen && s) {
            len += snprintf(buf + len, (size > len ? size - len : 0), " %s", scales[s]);
        }
        n %= scale;
    }
    return len;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

1. Keep your line-length under control. Horizontal scrolling is death on readability.
2. `strprep()` is extremely inefficient, and even assuming the destination is big enough, you don't check whether allocation of your needless temporary buffer succeeds. Better to fix that:

   ```
   char *strprep(const char *prefix, char *dest) {
       size_t prefix_len = strlen(prefix);
       memmove(dest + prefix_len, dest, strlen(dest) + 1);
       memcpy(dest, prefix, prefix_len);
       return dest;
   }
   ```
3. Assuming a user-supplied Buffer contains an empty string for no reason is certainly an *interesting* decision. It violates the principle of least surprise though, and leads to **Undefined Behavior** if the assumption proves unfounded.
4. I won't try to decipher what your cryptic single-character variables in `words()` are for. Do everyone (especially yourself) a favor and invest some more into finding good names.
5. Using `strlen()` to decide whether a string is empty? That's an \$O(n)\$ call where a primitive direct check is sufficient:

   ```
   if (!*dest) // dest is empty
   ```

   Most optimizing compilers in hosted mode will succeed in lowering it to the above, but why write that much more and rely on it?
6. Actually, check for zero beforehand instead. No need to do so after failing to put it into words some other way.
7. Either your example code violates the contract of `words()`, or words is buggy. I suggest fixing `words()` to not assume the buffer is pre-filled with an empty string.
8. Consider merging multiple outputs into one request. Don't worry, due to adjacent string-literals being concatenated by the compiler, that need not result in one humungous string-literal.

Comment: To not violate the principle of least surprise, should the code simply overwrite the already existent data in the user-supplied buffer? Or should it indicate some kind of error in that case?

Comment: Re: `!strlen(dest)`.  A good compiler uses analyze-ability of common std functions like `strlen()` to emit the same code as for `!*dest`.  Still, I would also recommend  `if (!*dest) ` or the like `if (*dest == '\0') `

Comment: @chux No doubt many good compilers do so. Still, why rely on having a sufficiently clever compiler to fix needlessly convoluted code in the first place...

Comment: I strongly disagree with 1. The days of 80-char screens is long gone. Most of us do programming work on 26-28-30" screens and this gives us plenty of horizontal room. And even if not, having a definition that will be visited once in a blue moon simply doesn't justify it. I'd never slice such an initial declaration into several lines even if it takes up more than several screen widths. Of course, if you print or copy to places like SO, this is a small nuisance that you have to solve. But it doesn't warrant changing your own habits regarding your own code.

Comment: @Gábor Well, I think both you and Deduplicator have valid points. Horizontal scrolling beyond a certain amount _is_ "death on readability"; that's why we wouldn't say that e.g. 350-character lines are perfectly valid. There's definitely _some_ threshold beyond which line length gets really inconvenient to deal with. It's just that that threshold isn't always 80 characters anymore.

Comment: I still don't really think so. If it really bothers you, just tell your editor to wrap lines. The underlying source code itself doesn't need to change at all.

Comment: @Gábor  "The days of 80-char screens is long gone." .  Hmm Stack Exchange here uses about a 90 character width.  With an auto-formatter, setting that line width to match the code review presentation width is then easy to perform and would have made review easier.   Code that does not present well after an auto formatter is higher maintenance.  As with such style issues (line width, braces, spacing, etc.) , code should adhere to the group's coding standard  vs  a personal preference.

Answer (score 3):

Consider what

```
char buf[256];
puts(words(0, buf));
```

with `words()` below.

`strlen(dest)` would be undefined behavior as `buf[]` was never initialized and so a *null character* may not be found with `strlen(dest)` before searching outside `buf` bounds.

```
while(n)
  ...
if(!strlen(dest))
{
    strcpy(dest, "zero");
}
```

Comment: If `!*dest` is used to check if `dest` is an empty string instead of `!strlen(dest)`, could the fact that `buf[]` is never initialized still result in undefined behavior?

Comment: @hjkl Treating uninitialized memory as a string or anything else is always a problem.

Comment: @hjkl  "could the fact that buf[] is never initialized still result in undefined behavior?" --> Yes, reading  uninitialized memory for any reason is a problem.  On 2nd thought it might be _implementation defined behavior_, and there are some special exceptions for reading `unsigned char`, but it is not a `!*dest` versus `!strlen(dest)` concern, both are problematic in OP's code.